# what is standard code and encode to send password over the net

Tags: objective-c

I am making a program like yelp. Some people have some accounts. So I got to send the password to the web.

Should I encrypt the password before sending it?

After that what would be the standard password policy others used?

Should the encrypted password be the one stored on the mySQL serve? In other word, there is absolutely no need for decryption?

Basically it's like [What encryption procedure I must use to send encrypted 'email' and 'password' values over the HTTP protocoll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137310/what-encryption-procedure-i-must-use-to-send-encrypted-email-and-password-va) but for objective-c

After the user logged in, my program need to tell the server that the user is authenticated already. Does my program need to keep sending password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one architecture you can implement, and you have to choose considering many factors, like performance, how many users, server architecture...

Basically, you must use https and not http, store hashed password (MD5, SHA, ecc.) and always check if hashed password is equal to stored hashed password.

You can implement also a "session" using token (you have to create a kind of API server side and then use it on client side) or pass username and password in each call to web service (web service must verify credentials every time is called).

Another "fast" (it's not so fast anyway) solution is to implement (both server-client) a standard protocol like (it's my favorite) oAuth 2. It's used by twitter and Facebook, you can learn more here: http://oauth.net/2/

Comment: Your web services must be running on a web server (usually https is running on 443 port) configured with SSL certificate you have to buy from a certificate authority - unless you install a self-signed SSL certificate. All main web servers support SSL certificates. Just try a google search and you'll find a detailed "how-to" for your web server.

Answer (score -1):

You might be looking for Base64 encoding:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html

Comment: It's not the answer. It's password encoding dude. I added 1 anyway for "effort"